# Wondering if I’m eligible for the stimulus

Tags: united-states, irs, covid-19, stimulus

I was claimed as a dependent on 2018 taxes and I didn’t file for 2019. I applied for the stimulus as a non filer and was accepted, but am I eligible? I was not claimed for 2019. I applied over a week ago and still haven’t received it, I chose direct deposit. Is that because I can’t get it? Do I have to file for my 2019.

Answer (score 2):

You said that you were not claimed as a dependent for 2019, but you didn't say whether someone *could have* claimed you as a dependent for 2019. If someone *can* claim you as a dependent, but chooses not to, you still do not qualify for the stimulus payment.

When you filled out the online "non-filer" form (which is basically an abbreviated 2019 tax return without any numbers), there was a checkbox that said "Someone can claim: You as a dependent". Did you check that checkbox? If not, then the IRS should send you a stimulus payment.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn’t file 2019 then they will go by your 2018 which you said you were claimed then. If you were claimed  as a dependent on your most recently filed tax return ( which from what I gathered was 2018) as a qualifying child or a qualifying dependent, they are not eligible to receive the $1,200 stimulus payment. Unless you are on disability or SSI.